# Netsuite - trouble with getting transaction id in glimpact plugin

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Trying to customize gl impact custom plugin for  the credit memo transaction record.  Having trouble with getting record id of it. I've explained cases below while it returns record id and while not.

Case 1: Does return record id of credit memo

1. Configuring Custom GL Impact Plugin to Credit Memo record
2. Accessing credit memo page
3. Selecting one record, first editing and then saving the record
4. Clicking GLImpact section from page above
5. Finally could see results and returns credit memo record id.

Case 2 : Doesn't return record id of credit memo

1. Configuring Custom GL Impact Plugin to Credit Memo record
2. Accessing Sales>Invoice page and selecting one record to test
3. Clicking **"Credit"** button to create a credit memo record
4. First editing and then saving the record
5. Clicking GLImpact section from page above
6. In this case record id of credit memo returns null

I'm using code below to get record id.

```
function customizeGlImpact(transactionRecord, standardLines, customLines, book) {

    var recid = transactionRecord.getId();
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recordId', recid); 
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the standard functionality for the getId() function in a custom gl impact plugin script. The documentation says: "Use this method to get the internal ID of a record or NULL for new records." [SuiteAnswers](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10269#bridgehead_N3098054)